# Switch between list view and grid view in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview

I implemented a collection view like in the link: https://iosrevisited.blogspot.com/2017/09/toggle-between-listviewuitableview-and.html.

I can switch between grid layout and list layout by tapping the right top icon as explained in the code of above link.

For switching between the layout, I'm reloading the collection view after setting the boolean which will decide whether it's list view/grid view. But I'm not getting the animation (as Google Drive iOS app is providing). I tried many things like adding collectionView.reloadData() inside UIView.animate, also tried layoutIfNeeded(), etc.

Can someone give a solution so that it will switch with an animation?

The following are my significant collectionview functions:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = view.frame.width
    if isListView {
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 120)
    }else {
        return CGSize(width: (width - 15)/2, height: (width - 15)/2)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
}
```

For switching between layout, I just reloadData().

Comment: Are you using `startInteractiveTransition` to go between the two layouts? You really should post relevant code (as text) into your question.

Comment: No, I'm not using that. I'm using just one layout. Sure, I'll add my code now.

Comment: refer -> https://github.com/Yalantis/DisplaySwitcher

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to change gridview to listview or vice verca.

Make two layouts

```
private lazy var listCVLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {

    let collectionFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 30)
    collectionFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: 80)
    collectionFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    collectionFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    return collectionFlowLayout
}()

private lazy var gridCVLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    
    let collectionFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    collectionFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 30)
    collectionFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (SCREEN_WIDTH - 80) / 2 , height: SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.16)
    collectionFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20
    collectionFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
    return collectionFlowLayout
}()
```

and finally when toggle view use this

```
  self.listCV.startInteractiveTransition(to: isListView ? self.listCVLayout : self.gridCVLayout, completion: nil)
  self.listCV.finishInteractiveTransition()
```

Comment: I am using the same approach but my app is getting crashed. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the collection was not prepared for an interactive transition. any soloution.

Comment: CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            CPHelper.dispatchMain {
                self.listPdfsCV.setCollectionViewLayout(AppData.isListView ? self.listCVLayout : self.gridCVLayout, animated: true)      
            }
        }
        CATransaction.commit()

Comment: try this @balkaransingh